# Difference Between "struct Obj* obj" and "Obj* obj"

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, elaborated-type-specifier

```
struct Element{
    Element() {}
    int data = NULL;
    struct Element* right, *left;
};
```

or

```
struct Element{
    Element() {}
    int data = NULL;
    Element* right, *left;
};
```

I was working with binary trees and I was looking up on an example. In the example, `Element* right` was `struct Element* right`. What are the differences between these and which one would be better for writing data structures?

I was looking up from this website:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-set-1-introduction/

Comment: In C++ both are treated as same.

Comment: @AnoopRana isnt there any difference in machine code? like in assembly

Comment: THey mean the exact same thing, but the `struct` keyword is a C habit where this is needed. Since you've got a constructor and therefore clearly C++ code, I recommend leaving out the `struct` keyword.

Comment: [Elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)

Comment: @TunaArıyürek `struct` in `struct Element* right;` is **optional** in C++. See some description and example in my answer below.

Comment: You should be using the `nullptr` keyword instead of the `NULL` macro in C++ code.

Comment: Learning C++ from geeksforgeeks is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, defining a class also defines a type with the same name so using `struct Element` or just `Element` means the same thing.

```
// The typedef below is not needed in C++ but in C to not have to use "struct Element":
typedef struct Element Element;
struct Element {
    Element* prev;
    Element* next;
};
```

You rarely have to use `struct Element` (other than in the definition) in C++.

There is however one situation where you do need it and that is when you need to disambiguate between a type and a function with the same name:

```
struct Element {};
void Element() {}

int main() {
    Element x;  // error, "struct Element" needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, `struct` keyword **must be used** for declaring structure variables, but it is ***optional***(in most cases) in C++.

Consider the following examples:

```
struct Foo
{
    int data;
    Foo* temp; // Error in C, struct must be there. Works in C++
};
int main()
{
    Foo a;  // Error in C, struct must be there. Works in C++
    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
struct Foo
{
    int data;
    struct Foo* temp;   // Works in both C and C++
};
int main()
{
    struct Foo a; // Works in both C and C++
    return 0;
}
```

In the above examples, `temp` is a data member that is a *pointer to non-const `Foo`*.

---

Additionally, i would recommend using some [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++.